# Import of another python function does not work

Tags: python, import, directory, file-structure

I have the following directory structure:

- GNS

  - gns_export.py
- new_structure

  - DB_Manager.py

and other Files that are not important.
When I now try to import a function from DB_manager.py in gns_export.py, I get an error.

In gns_export.py:
`from new_structure.DB_Manager import *`

Exception:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new_structure'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

Try the import with trailing dots:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: When I do this, I get the following error:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

If you're just importing the module and not running the file directly then @milchmannverleih's answer would work.

If for some reason you're trying to run it directly, then you can do it in the following way.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.pardir)
from new_structure.DB_Manager import *
```

You can add your parent directory in the `sys.path` of the program and it'd be able to find `new_structure` folder there.